# Derby database export as a single file?

Tags: java, database, derby

I am making a small application and I am using the embedded derby database ,I want the application to be able to save the whole database onto a single file which can be stored on the hard drive and also import the database by opening this file in the future.Any clues or examples on how can I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might help you out!

1- [Resource 1](http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.4/tools/ctoolsimport16245.html) with all detail

2- [Resource 2](http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.4/tools/ttoolsexporting.html)  with Export Detail only

3- [Using Java to Export/Import](http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.4/tools/ctoolsimportjdbc.html) Using Jdbc

To export all the data from a table to a single export file, including the LOB data

> SYSCS_UTIL.**SYSCS_EXPORT_TABLE** (IN **SCHEMANAME** VARCHAR(128),  IN
>   **TABLENAME** VARCHAR(128), IN **FILENAME** VARCHAR(32672),  IN
>   COLUMNDELIMITER CHAR(1), IN CHARACTERDELIMITER CHAR(1),  IN CODESET VARCHAR(128))

To export the result of a SELECT statement to a single file, including the LOB data

> SYSCS_UTIL.**SYSCS_EXPORT_QUERY** (IN **SELECTSTATEMENT** VARCHAR(32672),  IN
>   **TABLENAME** VARCHAR(128), IN **FILENAME** VARCHAR(32672),  IN
>   COLUMNDELIMITER CHAR(1), IN CHARACTERDELIMITER CHAR(1),  IN CODESET VARCHAR(128))

**Import and export procedures from JDBC**

You can run import and export procedures from a JDBC program.

The following code fragment shows how you might call the **SYSCS_UTIL.SYSCS_EXPORT_TABLE** procedure from Java. In this example, the procedure exports the data in the staff table in the default schema to the staff.dat file. A percentage (%) character is used to specify the column delimiter.

```
PreparedStatement ps=conn.prepareStatement(
    "CALL SYSCS_UTIL.SYSCS_EXPORT_TABLE (?,?,?,?,?,?)");
    ps.setString(1,null);
    ps.setString(2,"STAFF");
    ps.setString(3,"staff.dat");
    ps.setString(4,"%");
    ps.setString(5,null);
    ps.setString(6,null);
    ps.execute();
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question makes me wonder if you think you need to do this to persist your data. Just to be clear: You don't - your data is persisted on disk automatically. In fact all inserts and updates that have been committed are guaranteed to be persisted even if the jvm or machine should crash (as long as the disk is intact and the disk's write cache has been disabled).

D

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Derby with an embedded database, you should realize that it stores the "database" in a folder and set of files on your hard drive (assuming that it is not configured as an in-memory embedded database).

Thus, you can simply copy/save that folder somewhere else and open it. If you want a single file, then you can zip the folder containing the Derby database and move it around, etc.  Then unzip it and access it as normal.

If you really need a single file database, then consider using SQLite.