# How to store a derby database in a file

Tags: file, export, store, derby

When I start my java application, it creates a folder and stores a lot of derby database files inside. But I'd like to store the whole database in a **single file** instead - which I can open, close and share. I already read 
[this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18692158/derby-database-export-as-a-single-file) about some export functions, 
but it didn't help me much.

How I may hide that db-folder from the user and let him create db-files?

Comment: I'm afraid Derby doesn't work this way. Why does this matter to your user?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response! Well, my aim is to have a single encrypted db file, so the user can share his own data savely, and easily open the database of another user... any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that

1. Derby supports encrypted databases
2. A database can be placed in a jar
3. The database in the jar can be accessed in readonly mode

If you just aim to exchange databases securely, why not zip up the db-directory and encrypt that with the receiver's public key, then you could send that through whatever insecure channel you choose (email, IM, social media...)

Comment: Alright I'll try that...http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.0/manuals/admin/hubprnt43.html